# Limit the number of concurrently executed sub-processes in Activiti

Tags: concurrency, activiti

Well, pretty much as the question title states.

In Activiti, how can I ensure that I won't spawn 1000 concurrent sub-processes from my SubProcess container?

I would like to only allow, let's say 10 sub-process to execute, until all of them are processed.

Answer (score 0):

I might not have fully understand your question - It would be easier to understand if you defined what you need it for.

This should not be an issue, because Activiti uses only one thread run process machine

But if you need it you can create "for" loop (using script task, exclusive gateway and paralel gateway) to create exactly ten executions (something like activiti thread) and then recycle them when they finish their work.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: What is the use of the Sequential field when you define a Multi-Instance, then? If I set Sequential to false, I assume a bunch of subprocesses will be executed in Parallel.  It is the amount of these concurrent parallel suprocesses that I want to limit (not to exceed, 10 concurrent processes, for examlle)...  Am I mistaken in the way Multi-Instances ought to work...?

Comment: @Stratosgear "Am I mistaken in the way Multi-Instances ought to work...?"
Parallelism in activiti is Long-term paralelism and it will not create new processing threads (there is always only one thread). Reason for multiinstance is for example: when you want users to complete registration - you want them all to be able to complete it. If it was sequential, only one could complete usertask and when he does so usertask opens for another user and so on. I am not sure if I am describing understandably - let me know ;]